# Creating an install drive - can not open output file autorun.inf

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I am trying to make an install/boot drive for a computer that has no operating system and no optical drive. I used the ISO from Ubuntu.com and the burner from pendrivelinux.com. When the program starts writing to the flash drive, there is an error displayed that says :

```
"0    can not open output file E:\autorun.inf"
```

But continues to write data. After it has finished, I remove the drive and insert to the other computer and turn it on, but it never finds a drive to boot from.

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Run the PenDriveLinux USB Installer tool as adminstrator.

In Windows right-click on Universal USB Installer and select "Run as administrator".

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, it may be your antivirus program preventing the installer for opening the file. Try disabling it.